change font for section title but not section number in memoir class
Say you have numbered section titles, so that when you write \section{Foo} you typeset "1. Foo". I don't see how with the memoir class facilities I can change the font of the title ("Foo") separately from the number ("1"). We have \setsecnumformat where you could control typesetting of the number separate from the title, but \setsecheadstyle applies to everything, the number and the title. I could apply a global style in \setsecheadstyle and apply something that overrides it for the number in \setsecnumformat (like say \large in one and \small in the other) but I don't always know how to nullify a styling command I want to use for the title only, such as \MakeUppercase or microtype's \lsstyle.
I have played around also with redefining \section but it seemed to break starred versions, and I frequently got unexpected results. And I understand you don't use titlesec with memoir.
A concrete example is below, I'd like uppercase and stretched (\lsstyle or \textls) section and subsection titles with unaffected numbers.
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{microtype}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setsecnumformat{\csname mythe#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\mythesection{\normalfont\thesection .\ }
\newcommand*\mythesubsection{\normalfont\thesubsection\ }
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{(\roman{subsection})}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{Baz}

\end{document}


Note you should not be adding formatting inside the \theXtion macros. There are many other macros that are depending on these being "normal".

@daleif Are you referring to the parens in the new definition of \thesubsection above? Or just in general?

Parens are ok, font changes and trailing dot at not, they belong at the place where it is suppose to be typeset. Remember the value is also used in references where the formatting often aren't wanted

Here is a suggestion, it uses expl3 macros, see interface3.pdf for details. We use that fact that #1 is the name of the counter, and thus we can test for it and do stuff accordingly.
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{microtype,xcolor}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\setsecnumformat{
  \str_case:nnF {#1}
  {
    {section}   { \textnormal{\color{red}\use:c {the#1}.\space} }
    {subsection}{ \textnormal{\color{green}\tiny(\use:c {the#1})\space} }
  }
  % if not seen in the stack use this as the default
  {
    \use:c{mythe#1}\quad
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%\newcommand*\mythesection{nt\thesection .\ }
%\newcommand*\mythesubsection{\normalfont\thesubsection\ }
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\roman{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\subsection{Baz}

\end{document}


Here is an updated version based on the comments and the idea from @egregs answer
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{microtype,xcolor}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\setsecnumformat{
  \str_case:nnF {#1}
  {
    {section}   { \NoCaseChange{\textls[0]{\textnormal{\use:c {the#1}.}}}\space }
    {subsection}{ \NoCaseChange{\textls[0]{\textnormal{(\use:c {the#1})}}}\space }
  }
  % if not seen in the stack use this as the default
  {
    \use:c{mythe#1}\quad
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\roman{subsection}}
\setsecheadstyle{\normalfont\large\lsstyle\MakeUppercase}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\normalfont\normalsize\lsstyle\MakeUppercase}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\subsection{Baz}

\end{document}


Thanks, this seems to have a similar issue though when using \setsecheadstyle. For instance, add \setsecheadstyle{\MakeUppercase} and you get an error ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `RED'. Or with \setsecheadstyle{\lsstyle}, the section numbers/punctuation are stretched too

@tsj Just remove the colors, or define the color RED. It is a known issue with uppercasing. With \lsstyle you'll have to look up if there is a way to protect something from its effect.

Yes I don't need the colors, but try also \setsubsecheadstyle{\MakeUppercase}, this nullifies the lowercasing \roman{subsection}. I could reapply \MakeLowercase but what if I wanted a string like Sec to be printed along with the number? Was really hoping to find a general solution where I don't have to find special case solutions to protect/undo anything applied in \setsecheadstyle or \setsubsecheadstyle. For the current case it would be okay if I could protect from \MakeUppercase and \lsstyle though

See texdoc usrguide, wrap in \NoCaseChange (I used it in each of the lines in the str_case

As for lsstyle you'll probably have to look in the microtype manual, or ask another question.

Your idea is good, but…
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{microtype}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setsecnumformat{\csname mythe#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*\mythesection{\textls[0]{\thesection.}\ }
\newcommand*\mythesubsection{\textls[0]{\thesubsection}\ }
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{(\roman{subsection})}

\setsecheadstyle{\raggedright\Large\upperspaced}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\raggedright\large\upperspaced}
\newcommand{\upperspaced}[1]{\textls{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{Baz}
\subsection{Baz}
\subsection{Baz}

\noindent{\large(III)} % to show that the numbers aren't spaced out

\end{document}



Thanks, I would accept this also if I could. Had to use \NoCaseChange as pointed out by @daleif also to keep the subsection numbers lowercase

@tsj Wrapping that in egregs code still works.
